# Binding events to window in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, events, vue.js, bind, addeventlistener

I am quite new to Vue.js. Recently, I have encountered an issue with attaching/detaching keyboard events to window inside one of my components. Here are my methods:

```
created() {
  this.initHotkeys();
},

beforeDestroy() {
  this.discardListeners();
},

methods: {
  initHotkeys() {
    window.addEventListener('keyup', this.processHotkey.bind(this));
    window.addEventListener('keydown', this.removeDefaultBehavior.bind(this));
  },

  discardListeners() {
    window.removeEventListener('keyup', this.processHotkey.bind(this));
    window.removeEventListener('keydown', this.removeDefaultBehavior.bind(this));
  },

....
```

The events attach and fire up without any issues. However, when I switch components, the events still remain attached to the window. After a bunch of attempts, I found out that if I remove the `.bind(this)` part from all the callbacks, events detach successfully.

Can anyone, please, explain me why this happens?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Bind the method in the constructor instead, each bind return a new function pointer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`.bind(this)` returns a new function.

```
this.processHotkey.bind(this) === this.processHotkey.bind(this)
// => false
```

That's why removing the listener doesn't work. Lucky for you, that bind is not necessary, because component methods are already bound.

So just remove it.

Comment: No, at least not on the Vue docs, as this is not specific to Vue, it's just how Javascript works. MDN explains that `bind()` creates a new function, however: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Comment: No, i think it is related to Vue because Vue binds them automatically. 
I did not know this and struggled with binding myself, trying to make removeEventListener work, it did not because **bind** returns new function. 
It is better to put this information on docs.

Comment: That is documented as well: *"All methods will have their `this` context automatically bound to the Vue instance."* https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#methods Also, since without any binding, `this` would point to the `methods: {}` object, it can be inferred that this has to happen in the background.